# Why won't this wpdb get_results query return results?

Tags: php, mysql, wpdb

Having trouble with this query.  It returns an empty array even though I know the variables are correct and that multiple rows exist in the database that match.

```
$results_a = $wpdb->get_results(
                        $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * 
                                        FROM $wpdb->custom_table 
                                        WHERE 'FK_show'=%d 
                                            AND 'season`=%d",
                                        $FK_show,
                                        $season),
                                    ARRAY_A
                                    );
```

Comment: what is the value of `$wpdb->custom_table`?

Comment: there is a ~ tilda instead of a single quote after 'season'. I have fixed this but same problem is happening.

Comment: the value of $wpdb->custom_table returns 'wp_geasons' (it is the wordpress prefix + a custom table name).

Comment: I generated the following PHP code using MySQL: $sql = "SELECT * FROM `wp_gseasons` WHERE `season`=1 AND `FK_show`=94"; - which are the values for the variables I am using.  This query returns 17 results in MYSQL

Comment: both 'FK_show' and 'season' are of type INT(11)

Comment: ... and just in case I tried wrapping the $wpdb->custom_table in single quotes, but no results still. FROM '" . $wpdb->custom_table ."' WHERE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the query was done using ~ (tilda) quotes around columns in the SQL instead of the ' it worked.  It has something to do with the collation of my tables in MySQL, I believe.